# NSTableView scrollbar

Tags: objective-c, nsscrollview

The NSTableView I created with Xib. On some machines or on some versions, the scroll bar on the view will cover the content, but the normal performance is that it will not be obscured. I set the thickness of the scroll bar

`[[self.scrollview verticalScroller] setControlSize: NSMiniControlSize];`

but the scroll bar will become thicker when the mouse moves up.

1. I want to know why sometimes the content is blocked and how to modify it.
2. How to make the mouse move to the scroll bar without thickening the action.

Comment: 1. What is "Show scroll bars" setting in the General pane of the Sytem Prefs? 2. Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: 1.  automatically based on mouse. By the way,in the case of option 1, the MAC system of version 10.15.3 will block the content, and the MAC system of version 10.15.4 will be normal.I'm not sure it's because of the version difference.

Comment: Are scroll bars visible in other apps?

Comment: Yes.Other apps in my computer don't have this situation that contents near bounds,so I can't tell you other apps have same bugs or not.

Comment: 1. The visibility of the scroll bars depending on the prefs setting is a feature. 2. The thicker scroll bar is a Cocoa bug. It's reproducable in combo boxes, Character Picker, Safari, Finder and other apps.